# How to prevent of change Bootstrap Toggle?

Tags: javascript

I use [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in my website.

I need to when user try to change Bootstrap Toggle , i check a function and then order to change toggle button.

html :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="power-pump4" data-on="فعال" data-off="غیر فعال" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="success">
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sagiloseso/edit?html,output)

Comment: "I need to when user try to change Bootstrap Toggle" == click event !?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: What do you mean by order to change toggle button ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this what you are looking for:

```
$(function() {
  $('#power-pump4').change(function() {
    // your code here
    $('#power-pump4').bootstrapToggle('toggle')
  })
})
```

Comment: This is mistake. Because Toggle button worked automatic.